# Pod going to evicted state when running npm install

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have an azure agent pod that receives commands from Azure DevOps pipeline and execute those commands to build and deploy my projects.
One of my projects is an Angular project and when executing "npm install" to download the dependencies, the pod goes to Evicted state.
The message on openshift is: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container microsoft-vsts-agent was using 361715Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

[image: Pod when running npm install]

[image: Error message]

How can I solve it?
I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message says:

> The node was low on resource ephemeral-storage.

This node (brtbdvops002.devbtb) run out of the disk spaces that is used to host pods.